# Why are my text fields not showing for my rails site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, header, field

When I go to the registration page for my rails site, the "Register" header shows, but the text fields where the user inputs information to register do not show. Does anybody know why?

> Here is the code for my Register page:

```
<h2>Register</h2>
<% form_for :user do |form| %>
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Enter Your Details</legend>
   <label for="screen_name">Screen name:</label>
   <%= form.text_field :screen_name %>
   <br />
   <label for="email">Email:</label>
   <%= form.text_field :email %>
   <br />
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <%= form.password_field :password %>
  <br />
  <%= submit_tag "Register!", :class => "submit" %>
 </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

When I try to go to the page, all it displays is the "Register" header without any of the text fields at the bottom. I dont know why it is doing this. Someone please help. Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: Hint: `<% %>` vs `<%= %>`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow!

@jvillian mentioned the solution in their comment.

Remember to use
    <%=
to render the contents on the page.